# 403 - accessNotConfigured error while the required API is enabled

Tags: google-analytics-api

I'm experiencing a strange 403 error that keeps popping up since 26.09.2017. Here are the error details:

403
[domain] = usageLimits
[reason] = accessNotConfigured
[message] = Access Not Configured. Google Analytics API has not been used in project ******** before or it is disabled. Enable it by visiting https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/analytics.googleapis.com/overview?project=******** then retry. If you enabled this API recently, wait a few minutes for the action to propagate to our systems and retry.
[extendedHelp] = https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/analytics.googleapis.com/overview?project=********

The problem is that the project in question has the Google Analytics API enabled since years (around 2013).

I really can't figure out what could be the problem, it seems to be an API bug.

The error suddenly showed up, without any changes to the application or API Project, it just started raising at the end of September.

One more thing, the project also has access to the limited beta program for the Relatime Reporting API.

Any ideas?